# How to find records where a column value = [given array] in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Setup: Rails + Postgres.

I have table A with columns

```
id: int, name: string, address: string, s_array: varchar[], i_array: int[], created_at: datetime)
```

For a row, i need to find all the rows which have similar values.
In rails, then query would look like

```
row = A.find(1) # any random row
ignore_columns = %w[id created_at]
A.where(row.attributes.except(*ignore_columns))
```

This works if we don't have column with array type. 
How to find all records where a value = [given array]?

Edit: 
To be clear, I want to pass multiple columns in where clause where some columns are of type array. For values in where clause, I am passing hash (row.attributes.except(*ignore_columns) is a hash)

Edit 2: **Example:**

Lets say I have a Query table

```
Query(id: Int, name: String, terms: varchar[], filters: int[], city: string, created_at: datetime)

id = primary key/integer
terms = array of string
filters = array of integer (it is an enum and we can select multiple which is saved as array)
other fields = self explanatory
```

Suppose I have following rows

```
(1, "query1", ["john"], [0], "wall", <some_date>)
(1, "query2", ["eddard", "arya"], [0, 1], "Winterfell", <some_date>)
(1, "query3", ["sansa", "arya"], [1, 2], "Winterfell", <some_date>)
```

Now when I add new row

```
row = ActiveRecord of (1, "query4", ["eddard", "arya"], [0, 1], "Winterfell", <some_date>)
```

What I want is to search already existing records like this

```
ignore_attributes = %w[id name created_at]
Query.where(row.attributes.except(*ignore_attributes))
```

This query should return already existing query3 so that I won't need to add new row with name query4.

The problem is that because some column types are of array type, then passing them as hash/conditions in where clause is not working.

Comment: what columns you need to ignore before you check and hit the insert query..?

Comment: The ones in ignore_attributes array defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:-

```
    ##black list of attributes
   ignore_attributes = %w[id name created_at]

   MyModel.where(active: true).select(MyModel.attribute_names - ignore_attributes)

   =====The above query can also be chained as:- =====

   ##you have a city column too
    MyModel.where(active: true).select(MyModel.attribute_names - ignore_attributes).where.not(:city=>["Sydney","London"])
```

If you need this a permanent fix,you can add this line in your model.rb file.
but its dangerous.

```
self.ignored_columns = %w(id name created_at)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to find by single column, I want to pass hash of multiple values in where clause (clarified same in question)

Comment: Can you share any example...will try to help you out ?)

Comment: Added example in question @milind

Comment: i have updated my answer..let me know if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

use find_by to find_all_by and it will return all matching results.

Answer (score -1):

Your query in rails look like below

```
row = A.find(1)

where_clauses = row.attributes.reject{|k,v| %[id, created_at].include?(k)}

A.where(where_clauses)
```

Comment: Didn't get what you are trying to say. What you wrote above is same as my question.